# Geometric mean applied on row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I have this data frame as example:

```
Col1       Col2       Col3       Col4
   1          2          3        2.2
```

I would like to to add a 4th column called 'Gmean' that calculate the geometric mean of the first 3 columns on each row.

How can get it done ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way would be with [`Scipy's geometric mean function`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mstats.gmean.html) -

```
from scipy.stats.mstats import gmean

df['Gmean'] = gmean(df.iloc[:,:3],axis=1)
```

Another way with the [`formula of geometric mean`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean) itself -

```
df['Gmean'] = np.power(df.iloc[:,:3].prod(axis=1),1.0/3)
```

If there are exactly `3` columns, just use `df` instead of `df.iloc[:,:3]`. Also, if you are looking for performance, you might want to work with the underlying array data with `df.values` or `df.iloc[:,:3].values`.

Answer (score 4):

```
df.assign(Gmean=df.iloc[:, :3].prod(1) ** (1. / 3))

   Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4     Gmean
0     1     2     3   2.2  1.817121
```