# Convert pandas time series with monthly returns into a df with col cumulative yearly return

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.6

My df containing monthly returns looks like this:

```
df=pd.DataFrame((x*x).dropna(),columns=['mthly rtrn']) 

             mthly rtrn
2016-09-30    0.002488
2016-10-31   -0.004692
2016-11-30    0.003157
2016-12-30   -0.000503
2017-01-31    0.008019
2017-02-28    0.010055
2017-03-31    0.003435
2017-04-28    0.002577
2017-05-31    0.012107
2017-06-30    0.001089
```

How can I convert this into a df with columns Jan to Dec plus column for the cumulative yearly return. Lines should be the years 2016, 2017 etc. And the numbers should ideally be shown in %.

Desired output:

```
      Jan   Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep   Oct  Nov  Dec ANNUAL
2016 -5.0  -0.1  6.7  0.4  1.7  0.3  3.6  0.1  0.0  -1.7  3.7  2.0   12.0
2017  1.8   3.9  0.1  1.0  1.4  0.6  0.1   NA   NA    NA   NA   NA    9.3
```

where ANNUAL is the cumprod of the monthly returns.

What is the best pythonic way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you add desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first add additional columns **Year** and **Month** to your df using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146121/extracting-just-month-and-year-from-pandas-datetime-column-python), then use a [pivot table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) to create a new df to get the **index as Year** and **columns as Month**, around the **monthly return values**.

Once you have the pivot table, you can use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) along axis=1 to get whatever aggregation you need for each year.

I can't really comment on the aggregation because I'm not sure if by 'cumulative' do you mean additive or multiplicative. You might want to consider [cumsum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) or [gmean from scipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42436577/geometric-mean-applied-on-row), or if you prefer not to get scipy [this](http://www.jeffcomput.es/posts/2014/03/python-geometric-mean/) function works too.

Comment: to get cumulative annual return cumsum is probably the best way forward.

Answer (score 0):

I would first resample the data by month using the .resample() method:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.resample.html

Then use the pivot method to turn the rows into columns:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html

Then I would create a new column for the annual total:

```
df['annual'] = df['jan']+df['feb']+...+df['dec']
```

Comment: Could you please give me an example code how to use the pivot_table function? am stuck there. The df is already already monthly frequency (did that using asfreq function).

Comment: can you update the code in your question to show the new df with the code you used??

Answer (score 0):

I found a nice tool for what i need:
https://github.com/ranaroussi/monthly-returns-heatmap